# Reducing the artwork size for a universal iOS app

Tags: ios, image, ios-universal-app, image-size

As I say in the title of the question, I'm developing a universal app. At this point, the app has reached what I think it is a considerable size (some more than 30 MB), because I have quite a lot of images and icons, and for both versions iPhone and iPad. In fact, I have two versions of each image and icon (iPhone size / iPad size), and, in turn, I have also two sizes for each of this versions (non-retina display and @2x retina display).

I'd appreciate some tips from experienced developers regarding this issue and App Store submission: is it required to have two sizes for each image ("normal" one and retina - @2x)? I've been searching in the `iOS Human Interface Guidelines` and I'm not sure if it is a requirement or just a recommendation. Is there something I could do, in general, to minimize the size of the artwork in an app?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Juhana Has a game app the same requirements/needs than apps that are not games, in terms of artwork?

Comment: What does the app's purpose have to do with anything?

Comment: @Juhana just asking, maybe someone that is developing a game looks for a higher quality or level of detail in its artwork than someone that develops a general-purpose app...